# How do versions work and how are they measured?

Tags: version, system, measure

You see programs or games have versions displayed such as 1.2.5 (Minecraft), Version 3 Build 3000 (Sublime Text 3), or 1.9.2a0 (Python's Pygame).

How do these system work and how are they measured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, they're pretty much arbitrary, and depend entirely on the whims of the developers.

However, there are several common conventions that are followed by developers, with the most popular being in the form *major.minor[.build[.revision]]*, such the Minecraft 1.2.5 example. This convention can be used to communicate the significance of a change; for example, a major revision may break compatibility, while a minor revision might include new features, while a new build might contain bugfixes only.

Lots more info in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning.

Answer (score 0):

About the only consistent rule that people follow is that later releases have somehow higher version numbers (and even that's only a guideline).

In any case, what constitutes "higher" can often be indicative of some fatal flaw in the developers grey matter.

A common simple approach (and the one I use) is `<major>.<minor>`, where `<minor>` is increased for relatively simple changes (small improvements or bug fixes) and `<major>` increased (resetting `<minor>`) for more substantial changes such as massive new functionality.

But, as stated, that's only *one* possibility. IBM tends to use a `VxRxMx` model for version, release and mod-level, some companies (like Microsoft or Sublime Text apparently) insert build numbers, others insert different text based on the build such as `-beta` or `.cygwin`.

The number of possibilities are almost endless.